# Modifying the built in graphic format of colors

Tags: graphics, output-formatting, color, customization, elided-forms

Can users modify the default format of [colors](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Colors.html) in the front end?

`Red`

[image]

For example, dimensions, aspect ratio, EdgeForm? The motivation is the functional convenience in data visualization application especially when combined w/ Row, Column etc as in this graphic fragment:

[image]

Here would like to compress the horizontal bar, eg

`Table[Red, {5}] // Row`

by changing `AspectRatio` from squares to thin rectangles, and decrease the thickness of `EdgeForm`.

**EDIT**

Given

```
ds = {Red, Blue}
```

Would like to achieve something like this but on the box form rather than `Graphics`, to avoid scaling and padding problems when interacting with `Row` and `Column`

```
rectangleForm[w_, h_][c_] := 
  Graphics[{c, Rectangle[RoundingRadius -> 1/5]},
   AspectRatio -> (h/w), ImageSize -> {w, h}];
```

Then

```
ds // Query[{Map[rectangleForm[10, 20]] /* Row, Map[rectangleForm[20, 10]] /* Row, Map[rectangleForm[20, 10]] /* Column}]
```

[image]

Note the unwanted spacing in the last pais using `Column`. Maybe this can be remedied by use of `ImagePadding` or related, but this takes effort to coordinate.

Comment: Try the Graphics commands, like `Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{0, 1}, {2, 1.1}]}]` and you can make any shape of any color.

Comment: @bills, That works, eg `Table[Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[]}, AspectRatio -> 2, 
   ImageSize -> 10], {5}] // Row`

Answer (score 4):

You will really need to roll your own color bar, which isn't too difficult. Here is an example of making a highly customized color bar.

```
With[{n = 24}, 
  Graphics[
    Table[{Hue[i/n], Translate[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], {i, 0}]}, {i, 0, n - 1}], 
    ImageSize -> 550, PlotRangePadding -> None, AspectRatio -> 3/n, 
    Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None, 
    FrameStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[6], ImageMargins -> 0]]
```

[image: colors]

Answer (score 4):

Although I strongly suggest you just create and use your own formatting function if possible, e.g. `form[Red]`, the question of modifying the internal behavior is interesting.

You can either turn off the automatic color directive formatting and define your own [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes.html) rules on e.g. `RGBColor` to take its place, or you can modify the internal function used to produce the color icons.  To turn off the automatic formatting evaluate:

```
SetSystemOptions["TypesetOptions" -> "ColorDirectiveSwatches" -> False]
```

If instead you wish to modify the swatch routine it is contained in:

```
ElisionsDump`makeColorSwatches
```

You can view its definition with:

```
ToBoxes[Red]; (* preload; do not remove *)    
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
PrintDefinitions @ ElisionsDump`makeColorSwatches
```

Modifying that definition will change the form of all future color icons.  For example making a replacement on its [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html) to change the [`AspectRatio`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AspectRatio.html) of the `GraphicsBox`:

```
With[{dv := DownValues @ ElisionsDump`makeColorSwatches},
  dv = dv /. (AspectRatio -> _) :> (AspectRatio -> 2);
]
```

Now:

```
Table[Red, {5}] // Row
```

[image]

Comment: In fact I would prefer to apply operators eg form[verticalRectangle] to `Red` rather than modify the built in. I should rephrase or ask a separate Q? By built in I meant operate directly on the box rather than creating `Graphics`.  Doable?

Comment: @alancalvitti Could you clarify your goals?  (You can edit this question, IMO.)  You say rather than creating `Graphics`; I take this to mean that you want to use a formatting wrapper, such that `form[Red] // InputForm` is `form[RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]`, but `Graphics` (or at least `GraphicsBox`) will be used internally.  Is that correct?

Comment: I edited to emphasize that I'm looking to apply `Graphics` like options but to the box format if possible.